# Does UITextField secureTextEntry turn off autocorrectionType and autocapatilizationType?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

When I secure a UITextField using

```
textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

are the following traits affected in any way?

- `autocapitalizationType`
- `autocorrectionType`
- `spellCheckingType`

Comment: I think yes. Why you just not test is by yourself?

Comment: It must, how would the user tell. Why?

Comment: I did test it but it's not well documented :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is Yes**. They are all adjusted in a way that what the user types, is what appears in the text field, without any changes to the text.

Here is what [UITextInputTraits Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/secureTextEntry) says about it:

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isSecureTextEntry) BOOL secureTextEntry
```

> Identifies whether the text object should hide the text being entered.
>
> This property is set to NO by default. Setting this
>   property to YES creates a password-style text object, which **hides** the
>   text being entered.

If the text being entered was hidden and there was any type of correction/capitalization turned on, the user would not see what is being replaced/changed. Therefore, autocapitalization,
autocorrection and spell checking does not take place.